# findpeaks replacement zero length error

Tags: r, debugging, math

I am currently working with a raster comprised of 1,750,000 data points of a storm taken last winter. I am using the [`pracma::findpeaks()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/findpeaks) function in an effort to quantify and analyze periods of the storm. Every hour of the storm occurs over 90,000 data points, and I would like to get an hour by hour analysis. Over some hour intervals, the function works perfectly:

```
findpeaks(winddf$s1[1609931:1699931], nups = 3, ndowns = 3, minpeakheight = 10.79, minpeakdistance = 5)
```

- returns 110 peaks over this interval with these parameters for a peak

However, over another 90,000 count interval I get this error message after I run this:

```
findpeaks(winddf$s1[179133:269132], nups = 3, ndowns = 3, minpeakheight = 8.84, minpeakdistance = 5)
```

- > Error in xp[i] <- which.max(x[x1[i]:x2[i]]) + x1[i] - 1 : 
  >   replacement has length zero

The only changes made were the threshold `minpeakheight` and the interval at which I am viewing. The function works for all 3000 count intervals, some 8000 count invervals, and a few 15,000 count intervals, but I would much rather just perform 20 analysis of the 20 hours over 90,000 count intervals of the storm than perform 600 analysis using 3000 count intervals. I can not give the complete code or data as the data file is too large. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the findpeaks function. I found out that I had some non-numerical values in my vector that were producing NAs. I converted all NAs to zero with the line of code below and this resolved the issue.

dt$X5[is.na(dt$X5)] <- 0

Where dt is a dataframe and X5 is the vector you are plugging into the findpeaks function.